# Issue while merging multiple JSON Objects

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, object, whatsapp

I'm trying to auto-generate a JSON object for creating a dynamic interactive list message that will be sent to users on WhatsApp.

I need a JSON object in following format:

```
"sections": [
                {
                    "title": "Main Title",
                    "rows": [
                        {
                            "title": "row 1 title",
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "row 2 title",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

The above code will generate a list like this [image]

But I don't want to hard code the row's title part `{"title": "row 1 title",},{"title": "row 2 title", }` .
I tried using the below method where I fetch the title value from an array and merge it using spread syntax but it only returns undefined and doesn't combine all the objects.

**method.js**

```
    async function genJSON() {
            var arr = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row3']

    let data1, data2, d = {}
    let i = 0
    while (i < arr.length) {
     data1 = JSON.parse(`{"title": "${arr[i]}"}`)
    data2 = JSON.parse(`{"title": "${arr[i + 1]}"}`)
    i++
    d = { ...data1, ...data2 }
 

    }
console.log(d)
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
        
}
genJSON()
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Interactive List message: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages/

How can I achieve the following output {"title": "row 1",},{"title": "row 2", ..} ? Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two issues with your code:

- You were trying to merge two dictionaries with the same keys, hence the previous key gets overwritten. Instead, you should use a JSON Array and append to it.
- `data2` will be undefined when `i = arr.length - 1`

I've fixed both the errors in the below code snippet

```js
function genJSON() {
  var arr = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row3']
  try {
    let d = []
    for (const row of arr) {
      d.push({
        title: row
      })
    }
    console.log(d)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
genJSON()
```